# How to append an unordered list to en exisiting html element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

```
<input class ="metro" type="text" name="city">
```

This is input tag as a child of which I need to append an unordered list which is passed as an array to a function call as follows

```
$("input").autoComplete(["agra","bombay","delhi","chennai"]);
```

This autocomplete function accepts an array and outputs its elements as an unorederd list which I am not able to do.

Comment: Not getting you, can you please explain more?

Comment: If you're using jQuery UI's autocomplete widget, you need to pass the array to the `source` option: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#default

Comment: Do you want to write the function autocomplete or use the builtin function?

Comment: I want to write autocomplete function ot use the built in one ..

Answer (score 1):

$("input").autoComplete({source:["agra","bombay","delhi","chennai"]});

[Ref](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SvaGr/)

```
$(function () {
    var availableCities = [
        "agra",
        "bombay",
        "delhi",
        "chennai"
    ];

    $("input.metro").autocomplete({
        source: availableCities
    });
});
```

or

```
$(function () {
    $("input.metro").autocomplete({
        source: [
            "agra",
            "bombay",
            "delhi",
            "chennai"]
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/daV4d/)

[API DOCS](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement the function on your own, the basic block would be as follows

```
$(function () {
    var Cities = [
        "agra",
        "bombay",
        "delhi",
        "chennai"
    ];

    $("input.metro").autocomplete({
        $(this).append("<ul>");
        for(i=0;i<Cities.length;i++){
            $(this).children("ul").append("<li>Cities[i]</li>");
        }
        $(this).append("</ul>");

    });
});
```